# "IndexSizeError" when using Selection.getRangeAt on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, polyfills, legacy-code

while running `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)` on contenteditable div on modern browsers work as expected, 
Internet Explorer throws an "IndexSizeError" exception on some cases.

It happens when the AnchorNode of the Selection object is a TextNode and not a HTML node.

I thought maybe I would find a polyfill for that but none seems to be existing.

Is there any quick solution for that or an alternative for using `getRangeAt()`?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the same thing happens on Safari Mobile:
`IndexSizeError: The index is not in the allowed range.`

I found this post about it:
[Creating a Range object from a Selection object on Safari](https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html)

with this code:

```
var rangeObject = getRangeObject(userSelection);

function getRangeObject(selectionObject) {
    if (selectionObject.getRangeAt)
        return selectionObject.getRangeAt(0);
    else { // Safari!
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(selectionObject.anchorNode,selectionObject.anchorOffset);
        range.setEnd(selectionObject.focusNode,selectionObject.focusOffset);
        return range;
    }
}
```

After some adjustments for my need:

```
    var range = document.createRange();
        if(selectionObject.anchorNode) {
          range.setStart(selectionObject.anchorNode ,selectionObject.anchorOffset);
          range.setEnd(selectionObject.focusNode,selectionObject.focusOffset);
        } 
        else {
          range.setStart(div_element ,selectionObject.anchorOffset);
          range.setEnd(div_element, selectionObject.focusOffset);           
        }
```

The condition is for a case where the div is empty and `anchorNode` is `null` - so in that case it should use the div_element itself. 
if there is anchorNode (including TextNode type), the first part works well also on IE and safary mobile.